# Can I apply a style only to my applications components?

Tags: css, styled-components, shadow-dom

So I want to do something for my entire app like

```
  div {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

and this works fine. But as soon as I start including 3rd party components that expect `div` to have a different default value, it starts to cause problems - I need to spot fix any situations where this occurs.

Is there any workaround for this, such that components in my application get some default style, but it doesn't bleed into 3rd party stuff?  I'm using `styled-components` to apply styles, but the question could apply to other libraries.

Comment: You tagged your question ``shadow-dom``. ``<div>s`` inside shadowDOM will never be styled by global CSS. That is the main purpose of shadowDOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can tag third party components with a class, say `thirdParty`. Otherwise, if you can add a wrapper, with the tag, around third party components. Then you can use `:not()` like this:

```css
/* your local rules */
div:not(.thirdParty, .thirdParty *) {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>local one</div>

<div class="thirdParty">third party Parent
  <div>---third party child
    <div>------third party grand child</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>local two</div>
```